# Android TextView enable LinkiFy and Href tags

Tags: android, properties, textview, href, linkify

I want to set a text to the textview which contains href tags as well as normal http links. For ex, text like this `"please <a href=/'http://google.com' target='_blank'>click here</a>. or visit http://yahoo.com".`

The issue is I am unable to set both properties together. If I set Html.fromHtml to the text, the link with the href tag is highlighted. But the Linkfy property is not working for "http://yahoo.com" and vice versa. Is there any default property to enable both href tags and normal links in a TextView.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find one myself as I worked through a similar situation with [HREFs and telephone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28180537/1518546); in lieu of anything better, I am currently using a custom REGEX for calling Linkfiy.addLinks. Calling Linkify.addLinks with a mask ["also removes any existing URLSpans attached to the Spannable"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930215/1518546), which were created by Html.fromHtml. See the [Linkify Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution which works perfectly fine in my case and you can see in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418663/13961155

```
protected void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span)
{
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do something with span.getURL() to handle the link click...
        }
    };
    strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}

protected void setTextViewHTML(TextView text, String html)
{
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);   
    for(URLSpan span : urls) {
        makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
    }
    text.setText(strBuilder);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());       
}
```

and just textview to Linkify

```
Linkify.addLinks(description, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Answer (score -3):

If it's possible using an mx controls Label (spark does not support this any longer) u can use htmlText like the following example:

```
import mx.controls.Label //class need to be imported

var textview:Label = new Label();
textview.htmlText = "please <a href=/'http://google.com' target='_blank'>click here</a>. or visit http://yahoo.com";
yourItemContainer.addElement(textview);
```

This should work. But I don't know if it's possible for u using a normal label.

Comment: Thanks for de reply dude. But I am not able to find the above class Label in Android. May I know whether is it something related with scripting language ?

Comment: Well I had just figured that I wasn't in the flex tag anymore :p. I use flex and making a mobile app for Android and iOS. In flex I can use a label in my views.