# Open specific link in an other activity in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an application where I need to parse some text which may have some links.
When one of links contains a certain value, for example, `www.abc.com` and is tapped, I must open one of my activities.

I've tried the code in [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks/19989677#19989677) but but have been unable to make it work.

When I click on a link, I have nothing, I've tried to put some logging, for example:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.e("test",span.getURL());
}
```

But nothing is logged, it seems like I ever tapped on the link.

In my activity, I save data with an `AsyncTask` (it's ok, it works!) and in my `onPostExecute` method, I do:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   if(_flagOk){
        /* .... */
        setTextViewHTML(_contenu,datas); //where data is html code
    }
}
```

With the code of the link from above.