# Links with custom uri scheme does not work from TextView

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I'm trying to open a certain set of activities inside my application and for that I have added a custom uri scheme in my AndroidManifest file.

The problem here is when I use these link inside a TextView I get the following exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=numbers://imnumbers.com/buynumber (has extras) }

While from a WebView (links clicked inside a WebView) everything works fine. I've searched the web extensively for a solution to no avail.

This is how I parse html for TextView:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.getContent()));
textView.content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks) but it just doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click on links.

**UPDATE**:
The custom uri scheme is defined as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".simcard.NewBuySimCardActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_buy_sim_card">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="imnumbers.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/buynumber/"
                android:scheme="numbers"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. The problem was with the trailing slashes `\`. Removing them solved the issue.

```
<activity
    android:name=".simcard.NewBuySimCardActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_new_buy_sim_card">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:host="imnumbers.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/buynumber"
            android:scheme="numbers"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried the answer here.
[Android TextView with Clickable Links: how to capture clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks)

Have you tried the answer together with `setMovementMethod`?
`tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: Thanks your solution actually worked but unfortunately the same exception occurs. Seems the problem is with intent filters or the intent data!

Comment: @HamedMomeni just use custom `ClickableSpan` the docs are here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html