# set onclick on multiple links in single textview

Tags: android, hyperlink, xamarin, textview, clickable

I have a string in database that is like:

```
   string f = "this is the <a href="/page1"> first link</a> and this is the <a href="/page1"> second link</a>"
   textview1.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(f);
   url =?
   Intent i = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView,url);
   StartActivity(i);
```

the number of links in the string is different. I want to make all link in textview clickable and when user click on each of them, the url of that link send to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you setText using Html.fromHtml, the '' are replaced as UrlSpans in textView.
You can get each of url spans and set clickable spans for onClick function.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks) for the solution code.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the same using **SpannableStringBuilder**.

Simply initialize the TextView that you want to add 2 or more listeners and then pass that to the following method that I have created:

```
private void customTextView(TextView view) {
            SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                    getString(R.string.read_and_accept));
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black_30)), 0,
                    getString(R.string.read_and_accept).length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanTxt.append(" ");
            spanTxt.append(getString(R.string.t_and_c));
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    Utils.redirectUserToUrl(activity,"http://luxit-driver-terms.tookan.in");
                }
            }, spanTxt.length() - getString(R.string.t_and_c).length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
            spanTxt.append(" and ");
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.accent)), 48, spanTxt.length(), 0);
            spanTxt.append(getString(R.string.privacy_policy));
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    Utils.redirectUserToUrl(activity,"http://luxit-driver-privacypolicy.tookan.in/");
                }
            }, spanTxt.length() - getString(R.string.privacy_policy).length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
            view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
```

In Xml,use android:textColorLink to add custom color for ur link text

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="text"
     android:textColorLink="#000000" />
```