# Android TextView with Clickable Links: how to capture clicks in CustomAdapter ListView?

Tags: android, listview, hyperlink, textview, android-adapter

I have a `TextView` in `listview` which can have 2+ links. I had gone through to this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989677) to capture the event of a `TextView` but this is not working for a list view.

Here is my code:

**`getView` method**

```
if(ann.message.contains("<a href=")){
   setTextViewHTML(holder.announcement, ann.message);
}
```

**methods to make text clickable**

```
protected void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span)
{
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do something with span.getURL() to handle the link click...
            Log.i("YES-5.0", span.getURL());
        }
    };
    strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}

protected void setTextViewHTML(TextView text, String html)
{
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for(URLSpan span : urls) {
        makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
    }
    text.setText(strBuilder);
}
```

**This is my `TextView`:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAnnouncementMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:text="@string/message"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

I have tried with all the combinations of following attributes of `TextView' but still no success:

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:clickable="true"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding following line before calling `setTextViewHTML()`:

```
holder.announcement.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

So now my **`getView()` method** looks like:

```
if(ann.message.contains("<a href=")){
   holder.announcement.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   setTextViewHTML(holder.announcement, ann.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a XML Layout for your textview and that your clickable links all start with http:// il devrait etre suffisant d'utiliser les attributs suivants:

```xml
        <TextView
            ...      
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent" />
```

autoLink all means that all mailAdress, http link and phone numbers will be clickable. Just give a look at official documentation for further details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#ALL

Comment: Tried with your solution but bad luck.

Comment: I also want capture of every links in my textview

Comment: this should work if your links are in http format, try also to set             android:focusable="false"

Comment: can you post an exemple of the test in which you have links not correctly captured?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your movement method on your TextView?  Also, if your link comes as an a href tag, you can just use `Html.fromHtml` to build your `Spannable` for you.  For example:

```
TextView mView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
mView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
mView.setText(Html.fromHtml(YOUR_LINK_STRING));
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is I can not capture the link click with `setMovementMethod`.

Comment: Html.fromHtml handles placing the ClickableSpans for you, assuming you provide the link text in correct html format. (i.e. opening the link in a browser)

Comment: actually I don't want to open the link in browser I want to open the link within app in web view. That is why I want to capture the link click.