# how to control textView onclicklistener with autolink web setting or in other words,intercept autolink web OnClick event?

Tags: android

How to control textView `onclicklistener` with `autolink` web setting or in other words,intercept `autolink web OnClick` event?

For example,`String text="Lucy is very nice.Here is her link.https://www.google.com";textview.setText(text);`
when clicking "https://www.google.com",I can catch it and jump to my app activity not to web browser.
Textview has a property “autolink”.I set autolink as web.android:autoLink="web" So,android system can automatically detect the url.When clicking the url,it will jump to the browser.Now when clicking, I do not want jump to the brower,I just want to jump to my app activity and stay in app.

Comment: You should see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19989677/2367703).

Comment: I doesn't try it, but I guess you can use "Deep link" inside your app.

Comment: you want to show the link opening in an activity in the app right?

Comment: yes,url is detected by android system with my setting in TextView android:autoLink="web".But when I click the url ,it always automatically jump to the browser.I want to catch the url jump to the specific activity.Can you help me?

Comment: Check `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in WebViewClient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks you for all of your answers.Now I find my question's answer.There are two steps.

1.you need set Textview property. android:autoLink="web"

```
  <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text_view"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:autoLink="web"  
    android:text="Lucy is very nice.Here is her link.https://www.google.com" />
```

2.override URL onclick.There is an example.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView tv;  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);  
    CharSequence text = tv.getText();  
    if (text instanceof Spannable) {  
        int end = text.length();  
        Spannable sp = (Spannable) text;  
        URLSpan urls[] = sp.getSpans(0, end, URLSpan.class);  
        SpannableStringBuilder style = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);  
        style.clearSpans();  
        for (URLSpan urlSpan : urls) {  
            MyURLSpan myURLSpan = new MyURLSpan(urlSpan.getURL());  
            style.setSpan(myURLSpan, sp.getSpanStart(urlSpan),  
                    sp.getSpanEnd(urlSpan),  
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);  

        }  
        tv.setText(style);  
    }  
}  

private class MyURLSpan extends ClickableSpan {  

    private String url;  

    public MyURLSpan(String url) {  
        this.url = url;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onClick(View arg0) {  
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }  

}
```

}

3.The above code perfectly solved my problem.So when I click www.google.com in the Textview,the url will show out and jump to a specific activity.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not clear I am giving you answer that might help.
Create another activity i which you want to show the link :

```
   WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_search);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = bundle.getString("message");
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.left_webview);

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    //wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wv.loadUrl(url);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("URL :: " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

in the textView activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(TextViewActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("message","https://google.com");
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I mean:Textview has a property “autolink”.I set autolink as web.android:autoLink="web" So,android system can automatically detect the url.When clicking the url,it will jump to the browser.Now when clicking, I do not want jump to the brower,I just want to jump to my app activity and stay in app.Do you understand?

Comment: try it I think it will help you what you want

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly this is what you are looking for. In order to control the click event on the text inside the `TextView` you have to use HTML to create the link and use a `SpannableString`.

```
        // textView.setText("Lucy is very nice. Here is her link. https://www.google.com");
        final String source = "Lucy is very nice. Here is her link. <a href=\"scheme://some.link\">Click</a>";
        final Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(source);
        final SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(html);
        final URLSpan[] spans = spannableStringBuilder.getSpans(0, html.length(), URLSpan.class);
        final URLSpan span = spans[0];
        final int start = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
        final int end = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
        final int flags = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
        final ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked: " + span.getURL());
            }
        };
        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, flags);
        spannableStringBuilder.removeSpan(span);
        textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
        textView.setLinksClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

#### EDIT

So, according to your comment you can't use HTML so here is another example taking the text from the TextView with `autoLink` already set:

```
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    final CharSequence text = textView.getText();
    final SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    final URLSpan[] spans = spannableStringBuilder.getSpans(0, text.length(), URLSpan.class);
    final URLSpan span = spans[0];
    final int start = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    final int end = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    final int flags = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    final ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked: " + span.getURL());
        }
    };
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, flags);
    spannableStringBuilder.removeSpan(span);
    textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
    textView.setLinksClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I know your mean.However,I haven't used HTML.This is a chat app,you send text message,and I receive.The url detect is completed by android system with textview setting android:autoLink="web".I can not create the html link.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get what you are trying to say, but this will open a URL, or you can copy it to the cliopboard like copy and paste.

```
button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
```

Comment: Textview has a property “autolink”.I set autolink as web.android:autoLink="web" So,android system can automatically detect the url.When clicking the url,it will jump to  the browser.Now when clicking, I  do not want jump to the brower,I just want to jump to my app activity and stay in app.Do you understand?

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) {

setContentView(R.layout."activity you want to use"); Maybe don't use a textView. It sounds as if there is a better way around this. Or is it you have a web browsing app?


} }


} }

Comment: I'm doing a chat app. Chat list control must be textview.

Comment: Okay I think and I have your answer myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  
        if(url.startsWith("www"){
            return true;
        }

       
        return false;
    }
});