# TextView catch clicking on link when autoLink is set to "web"

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have TextView in my layout with `autoLink='web'` and when I click on it, internal internet browser is opened with URL that is provided as a text in that TextView and everything is fine. What I wish is to do something more with it, i.e. beside opening that URL in browser I want to do some additional actions. What is the least painful way to do it?

Best,

Deveti

Comment: Maybe you should use `SpannableString`

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,

I solved this by abandoning `autolLink='web'` and by parsing html url, creating `SpannableString` and setting additional spans.

So, let's say that I want to do the following:

- if user clicks on the part of the text of textView which is not url, method `someMethod()` should be called
- if user clicks on the part of the text of textView which is url, method `someMethod()` should be called and browser should be openned with given URL

So, first we have the content which is in the variable `message` and method `String extractFirstLink(String text)` will be used to get the url.

```
private static String extractFirstLink(String text) {
    Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text);
    return m.find() ? m.group() : null;
}
```

Note: in my case I know that I will have only one url, but if you can expect more than one url, this solution (found somewhere on StackOverflow, can't find it right now) will do the work:

```
public static String[] extractLinks(String text) {
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        String url = m.group();
        links.add(url);
    }
    return links.toArray(new String[links.size()]);
}
```

So, here is the code:

```
int contentTextColor = ...; // color of non-url text in textView
int urlTextColor = ...;
String message = notification.getMessage(); // content stored
final String foundLink = extractFirstLink(message);
SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString(message);

if (foundLink != null) {
    int startPosition = message.indexOf(foundLink);
    int endPosition = startPosition + foundLink.length();
    styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(urlTextColor), startPosition, endPosition, 0);

    ClickableSpan clickableURLSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            someMethod();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(foundLink));
            widget.getContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    };

    ClickableSpan clickableNonURLSpan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            someMethod();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableNonURLSpan2 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            someMethod();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    styledString.setSpan(clickableURLSpan, startPosition, endPosition, 0);
    if (startPosition > 0) {
        styledString.setSpan(clickableNonURLSpan1, 0, startPosition - 1, 0);
        styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(contentTextColor), 0, startPosition -1, 0);
    }
    if (endPosition < message.length() -1) {
        styledString.setSpan(clickableNonURLSpan2, endPosition + 1, message.length(),  0);
        styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(contentTextColor), endPosition + 1, message.length(),  0);
    }

    txtView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

txtView.setText(styledString);
```

There are some interesting things here. For example, when I wish to make span responsive to click, I have to use `ClickableSpan`, but! I must handle situation where I have format text1-url-text2. So, since all these three parts should be `ClickableSpan`s and text1 and text2 should not have underline, which is the default behaviour of it, I had to override `updateDrawState` method in my implementation of `ClickableSpan` for text1 and text2.

There is another catch, I had to create two implementation of ClickableSpan interface in order to have to work as intended. That's why I created `clickableNonURLSpan1` and `clickableNonURLSpan2`.