# How to achieve such a questionnaires form in Android ？Is there any good implementation?

Tags: android, excel, forms, user-interface

I have a questionnaire form like this:
[image: questionnaires form just like this]

The current implementation is to use `LinearLayout` ,`TextView` and `EditText` little by little layout to achieve. Very curious about those Excel App in Android,how their layout is achieved? Please give me some hints and inspiration。Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create table using HTML and load that HTML into `WebView`. 
Here's simple example:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

String myHtmlString = "<html><body>" +
                "<h2>This is a HTML Heading in Android WebView.</h2>\n" +
                "<p>This is a HTML paragraph in android WebView.</p>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<h4>Following is HTML Table in WebView</h4>\n" +
                "<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">\n" +
                "  <tr>\n" +
                "    <td>Android</td>\n" +
                "    <td>WebView</td>\t\t\n" +
                "    <td>100</td>\n" +
                "  </tr>\n" +
                "  <tr>\n" +
                "    <td>Android</td>\n" +
                "    <td>WebView</td>\t\t\n" +
                "    <td>200</td>\n" +
                "  </tr>\n" +
                "  <tr>\n" +
                "    <td>Android</td>\n" +
                "    <td>WebView</td>\t\t\n" +
                "    <td>300</td>\n" +
                "  </tr>\n" +
                "</table>" +
                "</body></html>";

mWebView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: Thanks . But  If use this way , how to get every  questionnaire answer ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How can I get the values in those tables if use HTML ?

Comment: You can make them links and [detect clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19989677/5985958) on those links