# Html decoding and linkify, losing URL parameters

Tags: android, html

I have a string that is HTML encoded and want to decode it and detect phone numbers and URL's to make them clickable after decoding it.

I've found

> Html.decode()

to decode the text and this makes links of the hyperlinks. Then if I then call

> Linkify.addLinks()

to it then the hyperlinks will then lose their extended paths.

Ex:

https://www.micromentor.org/?utm_source=volunteermatch&utm_medium=post1&utm_campaign=mentorrecruitment

will become

https://www.micromentor.org

If it was already a hyperlink.

**How do I HTML decode the string and linkify the string while also keep the extended hyperlink address?**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
{
    description.setText(Html.fromHtml(opportunity.getDescription() , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}
else
{
    description.setText(Html.fromHtml(opportunity.getDescription()));
}
Linkify.addLinks(description, Linkify.ALL);
description.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URLSpan or ClickableSpan to solve your problem.
View this: [Android TextView with Clickable Links: how to capture clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks)