# Linkify Phone-numbers using Regex

Tags: android, phone-number, linkify

I am trying to linkify phonenumbers using regular expressions, but i cant manage to apply it on my setText();

I've googled alot and it feels like im really close to success.

The code i got :

```
if(tag.equals("Customer")) {     
                     String name = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[0].trim());
                     String number = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[1].trim());
                     String SSNumber = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[2].trim());
                     String Address = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[3].trim());
                     String Postcode = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[4].trim());
                     String City = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[5].trim());
                     String Phone = "Phone#: " + xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[6].trim());
                     String Cell = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[7].trim());
                     String Email = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[8].trim());
                    // text.setText("Network "+xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "Name"));
                     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0]{1}[0-9]{6,15}");
                     Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, "Phone#: ");
                     //Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, xmlstring);
                     //Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, Phone);

                            text.setText("Customer: \nName: " + name +"\n" +
                                    "Customer Number: "+ number + "\n" +
                                    "Social Security Number: "+ SSNumber +"\n" +
                                    "Address: "+ Address +"\n" +
                                    "Postal Code: "+ Postcode +"\n" +
                                    "City: "+ City +"\n" +
                                    ""+ Phone +"\n" +
                                    "Cellphone#: "+ Cell +"\n" +
                                    "e-mail: "+ Email +"\n");



                            Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES) ;


                 }
```

As you see, ive tried multiple ways to linkify Phone and Cellphone-number.

I think the RegEx is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to call `Linkify.addLinks()` AFTER you have set up your text view, you're doing it before
2. Doesn't Linkify already support phone numbers, e.g. `Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS)`?

*Update*

Also,  in here: `Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, "Phone#: ");` the third argument is supposed to be the `Scheme`, "Phone#:" is NOT a valid scheme. It should be `tel:`.

Comment: 1. Okay, ive saw different examples for this, noone worked. 
2. Yes, it does, but i don't want Social Security Number or Postal Code to be displayed as a phone-number.
3. tel: didnt do the trick.

Comment: Does using the Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS work? Even if it matched more than you'd like?

Comment: Yes, it matched all numbers above 5 chars. Which is both Social Security Number (XXXXXX-XXXX) and postal code (XXXXX).

Comment: Phone number is 10 digits where as postal code is 5 digits and SSN is 9 digits. Can't you make use of lenghts?

Comment: Please show me how it could be possible? I'm out of ideas at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the call to

```
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES)
```

on the last line is wiping out the Spannables that previous calls to Linkify.addLinks() created. See the [Linkify Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29)